# Am I losing my mind, or is there glaring bug in the Google Annotated Timeline?

Tags: google-visualization

I see Google's example code listing dates for January, but the chart is displaying dates for February!

On my test machine, it is doing the same thing. I've told it to display dates for September, but it is displaying dates for October instead!

Can anyone else confirm this as happening?

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The months in the javascript date are 0 based not 1 based. So 0 is Jan, 1 is Feb, etc.
See
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp
and you might want to check out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: Oh my God, wow. I would never have guessed they'd do that to Months. I was just going to subtract by 1, but it seemed like such a hack. Now it doesn't. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly counter-intuitive when you look at a date.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not losing your mind. [The month in the Javascript Date object is zero-indexed.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) That means:

```
0  = January
1  = February
2  = March
3  = April
4  = May
5  = June
6  = July
7  = August
8  = September
9  = October
10 = November
11 = December
```

Answer (score 1):

ECMA-262 5ed, pp.165:

> 15.9.1.4 Month Number
>
> Months are identified by an integer in the range 0 to 11, inclusive.